# What is a good strategy for finding and killing Aeonaxx in Deepholm?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

There are countless comment threads filled with spam across the Internet for strategies on camping and killing **Aeonaxx**. **Aeonaxx** is a rare spawn in Deepholm that drops the *Reins of the Phosphorescent Stone Drake*. I've been camping him now for probably ~5 days on and off while running NPCscan and doing work. I'm mostly in a static position. For those with experience on camping/killing Aeonaxx, can you please provide a strategy for what worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I assume you've read [these](http://www.wowhead.com/item=63042#comments) [three](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=50062#comments) [threads](http://www.wowhead.com/forums&topic=179997). To sum it up:

- Aeonaxx spawns around the temple of earth, you can sit on the entrance to **The Stonecore** with *npcscan* running
- Aeonaxx is extremely rare, in your 5 days there is no guarantee he even spawned.
- If you see the corpse of Aeonaxx, it is highly unlikely he will respawn again that day

Unfortunately, the best strategy is to plant yourself down and check **Sound in Background** in the game options. *npcscan* will play a loud alert when it locates the dragon. So it is best to do something outside of WoW and wait.